# Get Nike API Access Key

Tags: api, nikeplus-api

I am trying to make requests to the Nike+ API to get information but I do not know where to get a long-term access token from.

I know that I am making the actual request correctly (using AJAX) because I send the same request that Nike+ send when using their test console (I take it from the Chrome network tab when the test console sends). This request works for about an hour before saying the token has expired.

How do I get a long-term token? I have looked around the API and can't find it which makes me think I am missing something pretty obvious here.

## Update (12/09/2016)

I need to have a client id to start making the implicit flow requests. I took one from the network tab of the chrome browser (from when I logged in) and used it as a parameter(as well as other things) for the first api call but it said it couldn't load partner details.

Any ideas? Am i even allowed to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Nike+ API uses OAuth 2 for authentication. In his API there is no long-term token, but you can use refresh_token (30 days) to get new access_token (bound with expired_in) when your authentication expires and get unauthorized response. You can read more at [Nike+ API documentation](https://developer.nike.com/documentation/api-docs/user-connections/oauth-services/auth-code-grant-flow.html).